# Implementing Count() and Group By() in MySQL using two Tables

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by

I have two separate Tables `tbl_name` and `tbl_parent`.

This is what my database looks like:

**tbl_name**

```
member_id   first_name   last_name
    0          John        Doe
    1          Jane        Doe
    2          Julie       Doe
    3          Billy       Joe
```

**tbl_parent**

```
 member_id   parent_id
    0          Null
    1           0
    2           0
    3          Null
```

As you can see tbl_name holds data about the members, while tbl_parent is used to define the relationship of each record in tbl_name.

The parent_id in tbl_parent is just referencing the member_id, so based on the given table, John Doe is the parent of both Jane Doe and Julie Doe.

Now I'm trying to count all those who have parent_id 0,

this was my query, it worked fine when they are not separated in a different table.

```
select *, count(parent_id) from tbl_parent group by parent_id
```

The difficulty I'm having is working with two tables I can't get it to display correctly

I would like the output to be:

```
member_id   first_name   last_name  child
    0          John         Doe       2
    1          Jane         Doe       0
    2          Julie        Doe       0
    3          Billy        Joe       0
```

Comment: Check out the SQL Join commands: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

This should help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT tbl_name.*, COUNT(tbl_parent.member_id) AS child
FROM tab_name
LEFT JOIN tbl_parent ON tbl_name.member_id = tbl_parent.parent_id
GROUP BY tbl_name.member_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by simple use of Left join:

Try this:

SELECT c.*, COUNT(p.member_id) child
FROM tab_name c
LEFT JOIN tbl_parent p ON c.member_id = p.parent_id
GROUP BY c.member_id

Please have a look following link for more knowledge about Joins in MySQL
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select n.*, count(parent_id) Child
from tbl_name n
left outer join tbl_parent p on n.member_id = p.parent_id
GROUP BY n.member_id, first_name, last_name
```